# The right way to do a Twitter-like mask loading animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to make a loading screen similar to Twitter's loading overlay here:

[image]

I'm not sure if the way I've approached this is the "right" way to do things at all. My concerns are many:

- Is there a better way to pick the mask image I'm using for various screen sizes? The mask needs to extend to the edges of the screen to work with the background color, so I'm making it the size of the phone's possible bounds.
- Are animations being handled correctly? This is my first use of `CATransaction` for anything.
- Should I be adding the view to the tab bar controller's view like I'm doing?
- Is there any way to abstract this out, or a better place to put this in the app's lifecycle? As of now I need to duplicate this code and place it any controller that could be a starting point (two controllers as of now).

You can see what I've written so far below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    prepareLoadingOverlay()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    animateMask()
}

var mask: CALayer?
var blueView: UIImageView?

func prepareLoadingOverlay() {
    let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

    var cutoutImage: UIImage?

    switch size.height {
    case 420:
        cutoutImage = CutoutMap.Image480 // UIImage
    case 568:
        cutoutImage = CutoutMap.Image568
    case 667:
        cutoutImage = CutoutMap.Image667
    case 736:
        cutoutImage = CutoutMap.Image736
    default:
        cutoutImage = CutoutMap.Image667
    }

    if let tabBarViewController = self.tabBarController,
        let cutout = cutoutImage {
            let containerFrame = tabBarViewController.view.frame

            blueView = UIImageView.init(frame: containerFrame)
            blueView!.image = UIImage.imageFromColor(Color.Blue)

            self.mask = CALayer()
            self.mask?.contents = cutout.CGImage
            self.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            self.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            self.mask?.position = CGPoint(x: containerFrame.size.width/2, y: containerFrame.size.height/2)

            tabBarViewController.view.addSubview(blueView!)
            blueView!.layer.mask = self.mask
    }
}

func animateMask() {
    let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

    if let mask = self.mask {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
                self.blueView?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            mask.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width*15, height: size.height*15)
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
        mask.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using hard-coded image sizes for the various resolutions, just set a single image's size proportional to the window size.

Comment: Are you not getting the results you're expecting? Before I looked at your code, the first thought that came to my mind was that I would use a scale transform. Looks like you're animating the bounds.